# Win32 API TerminateProcess() returns success but process is not killed

Tags: winapi, process, kill, terminate

I'm using TerminateProcess() to kill another process (I know it's not the best way, but it's existing code that is already deployed). In most cases everything works as expected, but in two specific machines, the process is not killed, even though the TerminateProcess() return a non-zero value which means success.

We tried to kill the process from the task manager and it was killed.

The documentation says that the process will terminate only after all IO operations are finished or canceled, so we thought that maybe there is some pending IO operation, but if that was the case, task manager would also be unable to kill the process.

The process that calls TerminateProcess() is running under the system account, so we don't think it's a permission issue (also, if it was a permission issue we would expect the function to return ACCESS_DENIED).

The process that we are trying to kill is running as an initial program in an RDP session.

Does anyone have an idea about what can cause this behavior? Or maybe suggest ways to troubleshoot? We tried Process Monitor and Process Explorer but we didn't find anything.

Comment: *We tried to kill the process from the task manager and it was killed* also only call `TerminateProcess` (`NtTerminateProcess`) - so if  task manager kill it - something wrong in your description

Comment: It turns out that the user initial programs is started twice for some reason. We only kill the first instance. When I tried from task manager it killed the second instance. So it's not TerminateProcess(). Now I need to understand why it's running twice. Thanks.